# Starting the communication between server and client

Tags: java, client-server

When a client wants to estabilish a connection to a server, must the communication always start from the client?

I mean the first step has to be done by client? For instance, I have a client that connects to a server through `Socket`. The client must send for first a message?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Server can't know when client wants to connect to it. So, if we're about Sockets for example in java, client can connect to the server, and server can send a message to this client without a client need to send to server a message first. Here is an example

SERVER:

```
int port = 3456;
ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(port);
Socket socket;
socket = server.accept();
socket.getOutputStream().write(10);
```

CLIENT:

```
Socket socket = new Socket("server", 3456);
socket.getInputStream().read()
```

So client connects to the server. Server accepts the connection and writes the data to be sent to client. Client uses input stream to read this data. Thus, client may not send a message first, but needs only to connect to server.

Answer (score 2):

Terminology is simple. Client is a process which sends request to the server. So yes communications starts from client.

Answer (score 2):

Client and Server are flexible terms - the normal description is that the Client requests data from a Server, but which machine is deemed the Client and which is the Server is up to you.

There are technical issues with Servers initiating connections to Clients. For example a server must know the address of the client - this becomes a big problem if you're traversing networks using NAT, etc. Usually the Server has a single, global address which all the clients know.

You've also got firewalls and other network protection measures which typically only allow connections to be initiated from Clients to Servers.

Answer (score 0):

there are a few solutions to start the communication on the server side :

- the Push technology, or server push, describes a style of Internet-based communication where the request for a given transaction is initiated by the publisher or central server. If you use javascript you can use the comet technology to do a server push.
- In java there is an another option to push with is message driven communication where the server sends out JMS messages and the clients can process
- If you use UDP multicast then the same can be reached as with JMS, but one level lower (also supported in Java)